# Complex numbers - find value of $x$ and $y$ in $2x + 3jy = -6 +12j $

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the values of $x$ and $y$ in $$ 2x + 3jy = -6 + 12j $$

How do I solve this ?

I want to move the real part and the imaginary part to one side . Am I right to say

$2x + 6 = 12 j - 3 jy $

Comment: Are $x,y$ real?

Comment: What does $j$ symbolize ?

Comment: $j=\sqrt{-1}$ I suppose?

Comment: @Rebellos The symbol for the imaginary unit as used by electricians, to avoid confusion with $i$ for current.

Answer (score 1):

Noting that $j$ is the imaginary part of a complex number, it will do good to just equate the coefficients on the both sides of the equality. We have, $$2x+j(3y)=-6+12j \implies (2x)=6 \, \text{ and } (3y)=12 \implies x=-3 \, \text{ and } y=4^{1}$$

<sup>$^{1}$ Assuming $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Two complex numbers $z=x+yj$ and $\zeta=a+bj$, where $a,b,x,y\in\mathbb R$ are equal if and only if $x=\Re(z)=\Re(\zeta)=a$ and $y=\Im(z)=\Im(\zeta)=b$.

In your case
$$
2x+3yj = -6+12j \Leftrightarrow 2x=-6\text{ and }3y=12.
$$
*(If $x$ and $y$ are real.)*

But your rearrangement is also fine, since
$$
2x+6=(12-3y)j
$$
have on RHS a real number while the LHS is complex. So you can deduce $2x+6=0$ and $12-3y=0$.